# C# & ASP.NET Core : foreign key violation for custom IdentityUser

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I want to use an extended `IdentityUser` class with additional attributes:

```
namespace SpaceShip.Model;

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

public class UserEntity : IdentityUser
{
    // Additional properties 
}
```

Using its Id as a foreign key in my model class:

```
public class SpaceShip
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    // Navigation property
    public UserEntity User { get; set; }
}
```

I use two separate `DbContext`s to separate concerns:

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<SpaceShipModel> SpaceShips { get; set; } 

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        // Configure the relationship between SpaceShip and AspNetUsers (UserEntity)
        builder.Entity<SpaceShipModel>()
            .HasOne<UserEntity>(s => s.User)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(s => s.UserId)
            .IsRequired()
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade); 
    }
} 

public class UserContext : IdentityDbContext<UserEntity>
{
    public UserContext(DbContextOptions<UserContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        // Additional configuration
    }
}
```

When I try to create a new `SpaceShip` with a valid `userId`:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class SpaceShipController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly SpaceShipService _spaceShipService;

    public SpaceShipController(SpaceShipService spaceShipService)
    {
        _spaceShipService = spaceShipService;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(string name, string userId)
    {
        await _spaceShipService.CreateSpaceShipAsync(name, userId);
        return Ok(); 
    }
}
```

I get this error:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
>
> Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 23503: insert or update on table "SpaceShips" violates foreign key constraint "FK_SpaceShips_UserEntity_UserId"
>
> DETAIL: Key (UserId)=(b3a23cba-ad21-4e5a-9b25-8c5e139c67fe) is not present in table "UserEntity"

It happens because the constraint `FK_SpaceShips_UserEntity_UserId` doesn't refer to `AspNetUsers`:

```
-- Constraint: FK_SpaceShips_UserEntity_UserId

-- ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS public."SpaceShips" DROP CONSTRAINT IF EXISTS "FK_SpaceShips_UserEntity_UserId";

ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS public."SpaceShips"
    ADD CONSTRAINT "FK_SpaceShips_UserEntity_UserId" 
        FOREIGN KEY ("UserId")
        REFERENCES public."UserEntity" ("Id") MATCH SIMPLE
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION
            ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

The problem can be temporarily solved by modifying `FK_SpaceShips_UserEntity_UserId` to refer to `AspNetUsers`:

```
-- Constraint: FK_SpaceShips_UserEntity_UserId

-- ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS public."SpaceShips" DROP CONSTRAINT IF EXISTS "FK_SpaceShips_UserEntity_UserId";

ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS public."SpaceShips"
    ADD CONSTRAINT "FK_SpaceShips_UserEntity_UserId" 
        FOREIGN KEY ("UserId")
        REFERENCES public."AspNetUsers" ("Id") MATCH SIMPLE
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION
            ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

But it should be configured by Entity Framework and subsequent migrations may overwrite it. I don't understand why doesn't the foreign key constraint refer to `AspNetUsers` by default.

Answer (score 1):

Using only one Database Context solved the issue:

```
public class AppDbContext : IdentityDbContext<UserEntity>
{
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<SpaceShipModel> SpaceShips { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        // Map UserEntity to AspNetUsers table
        builder.Entity<UserEntity>().ToTable("AspNetUsers");

        // Configure the relationship between SpaceShip and UserEntity (AspNetUsers)
        builder.Entity<SpaceShipModel>()
            .HasOne<UserEntity>(s => s.User)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(s => s.UserId)
            .IsRequired()
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
    }
}
```

However it is still unclear to me how can I use two separate contexts.

Comment: Why do you want to use two separate contexts, given that the entities are related and both must be referenced to make the model work?

Comment: I thought It would be easier to manage my models that way and that it is the recommended pattern.

Comment: I wasn't aware of it being the recommended pattern, though I'm sure that's due to my not having read enough. Is it possible they mean separate _instances_ of the contexts, rather than separate context classes?